# use views in objective-c code

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

```
const char *sqlSubCountries="SELECT subCountryID,subCountryName,subCountryComment,image,priority,hasRegions,navigationKey\
    FROM subCountries\
    ORDER BY priority ASC";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlSubCountries, -1, &statement, NULL);
```

this is just an code example. How can I use the views stored in the sqlite (or any other) database in objective-c code?

Comment: You want to store `UIView` xib's and/or the code to create those `UIView` objects within a SQLite db?  I'm certain it can be done, but ewwwwww... why??

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: I HOPE the OP means *[SQL views](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html)*.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann No of cause! I have a couple of views in db for sake of security and ..... I want to use them in objective-c code like in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a long way to go, but you need to learn to archive your objects then save them as binary data in your SQLite database. Look for FMDB on github for a good Objective C sqlite3 layer.

I'd get stuck into learning the ins and outs of the Cocoa NSCoding protocol, and read the "Archives and Serialisation Programming Guide".